# Unable to install PHP-FPM on Apache (Failed to connect to FastCGI server)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php5, fastcgi, php-fpm

I have been having problem installing `php-fpm` for use with `apache2-mpm-worker`. T[his is the guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/using-php5-fpm-with-apache2-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts) that I am following.

According to the guide's Step 5,

```
Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -pass-header Authorization
```

However I cannot find `php5-fcgi` at `/usr/lib`, but only `/usr/bin/php5-cgi` and `/usr/bin/php-cgi`, which I am not sure if they are the same.

So I changed the lines in Step 5 to:

```
Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/bin/php5-fcgi
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/bin/php5-fcgi -host 127.0.0.1:9000 -pass-header
```

On restarting Apache, it's logs gave the errors:

```
[notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[alert] (4)Interrupted system call: FastCGI: read() from pipe failed (0)
[alert] (4)Interrupted system call: FastCGI: the PM is shutting down, Apache seems to have disappeared - bye
[notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 configured -- resuming normal operations
[notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 16348)
```

And on loading the index page

```
[error] [client 10.0.2.2] (111)Connection refused: FastCGI: failed to connect to server "/usr/bin/php5-cgi": connect() failed
[error] [client 10.0.2.2] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/bin/php5-cgi"
[error] [client 10.0.2.2] File does not exist: /var/www/mydomain/public/favicon.ico
```

**Question:** Any idea why `php5-fcgi` is missing, and how should this problem be fixed? Thank you!! :)

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not. I switched to nginx and managed to get php-fpm to work. I will revisit this issue again with Apache, sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set it back to

```
Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
```

It doesn't exist because the next line intercepts the call and forwards it to the fpm

```
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization -idle-timeout 3600
```

Comment: Great. In my case, the vhost config file is generated by ISPCONFIG, and I had to change `FastCgiExternalServer ALIAS_NAME -host 127.0.0.1:9016` ... to `FastCgiExternalServer ALIAS_NAME -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock` to get it working. Still don't know why it was not generated correctly ?!

Comment: The `-socket` part did the trick in my case (Ubuntu 12.04, upgraded PHP from standard 5.3 to 5.5).